# Java Swing JSplitPane not showing as intended

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to make a program thats based upon 5 Jsplitpanes and internal components, but they don't seem to get along well. Since when I run the application all the split panes are concentrated on the upper left corner

[image]

The code is really simple:

```
projectExplorer = new ProjectExplorer();
    editorExplorer = new EditorExplorer();
    favDownload = new FavDownload();
    favDownloadExplorer = new FavDownloadExplorer();
    //Define the listeners
    addComponentListener(new ResizeListener());

    horTopPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
    horTopPane.setLeftComponent(projectExplorer);
    horTopPane.setRightComponent(editorExplorer);

    horBotPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
    horBotPane.setLeftComponent(favDownload);
    horBotPane.setRightComponent(favDownloadExplorer);

    verticalPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
    verticalPane.setTopComponent(horTopPane);
    verticalPane.setBottomComponent(horBotPane);


    setContentPane(verticalPane);
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
        @Override
        public void run() {
            resizeComponents();
        }
    }, 100);
```

the resizeComponents method is

```
public void resizeComponents(){
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    horTopPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, (height/2)+(height/4)));
    horTopPane.setSize(horTopPane.getMinimumSize());
    horBotPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, (height/8)));
    horBotPane.setSize(horBotPane.getMinimumSize());
    projectExplorer.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width/8, horTopPane.getHeight()));
    projectExplorer.setSize(projectExplorer.getMinimumSize());
    editorExplorer.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width/2, horTopPane.getHeight()));
    editorExplorer.setSize(editorExplorer.getMinimumSize());
    favDownload.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width/8, horBotPane.getHeight()));
    favDownload.setSize(favDownload.getMinimumSize());
    favDownloadExplorer.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width/2, horBotPane.getHeight()));
    favDownloadExplorer.setSize(favDownloadExplorer.getMinimumSize());
}
```

it started just as setSize, but for some reason it didn't resize them at all, then I putted setMinimumSize and it didn't resize it either, but when i move the elements a bit on the program they all go to its minimum size, am I missing something?

I've already made a few Java GUI programs, but this one just doesn't want to work properly.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Don't mess with the component sizing hints...Don't modify the UI from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: I messed with the sizing since when I didn't have that it was the same as it shows now :/ and I wait the 0.1 seconds because if i do it from the start the width and height is 0 oddly, any suggestions?

Comment: All components have a zero size until the layout manger is invoked. The layout manager is invoked when you do a pack() or the frame is made visible. It is the layout managers job to set the size/location of components.

Comment: What does the `ResizeListener` do?

Comment: Override the `getPreferredSize` method of your custom components and return a "default" size

Answer (score 1):

To start with, don't mess with `setMinimum/Maximum/PreferredSize`, have a look at [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) for more details

Next, don't update the state of UI components from any thread other than the Event Dispatching Thread, Swing is not thread safe.  `java.util.Timer` will trigger event notification within it's own thread context.

Next, consider overriding (at least), `getPreferredSize` from your custom components and return a default value, for example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SplitPaneTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SplitPaneTest();
    }

    public SplitPaneTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private final ProjectExplorer projectExplorer;
        private final EditorExplorer editorExplorer;
        private final FavDownload favDownload;
        private final FavDownloadExplorer favDownloadExplorer;
        private final JSplitPane horTopPane;
        private final JSplitPane horBotPane;
        private final JSplitPane verticalPane;

        public TestPane() {
            projectExplorer = new ProjectExplorer();
            editorExplorer = new EditorExplorer();
            favDownload = new FavDownload();
            favDownloadExplorer = new FavDownloadExplorer();

            horTopPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
            horTopPane.setLeftComponent(projectExplorer);
            horTopPane.setRightComponent(editorExplorer);

            horBotPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
            horBotPane.setLeftComponent(favDownload);
            horBotPane.setRightComponent(favDownloadExplorer);

            verticalPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
            verticalPane.setTopComponent(horTopPane);
            verticalPane.setBottomComponent(horBotPane);

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(verticalPane);
        }
    }

    protected abstract class AbstractPane extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

    public class ProjectExplorer extends AbstractPane {

        public ProjectExplorer() {
            setBackground(Color.RED);
        }

    }

    public class EditorExplorer extends AbstractPane {

        public EditorExplorer() {
            setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        }

    }

    public class FavDownload extends AbstractPane {

        public FavDownload() {
            setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
        }

    }

    public class FavDownloadExplorer extends AbstractPane {

        public FavDownloadExplorer() {
            setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        }

    }

}
```

If you have to modify the divider's location consider using [`JSplitSpane#setDividerLocation(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html#setDividerLocation(double)) or [`JSplitSpane#setDividerLocation(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html#setDividerLocation(int))

Take a look at [How to Use Split Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html) for more details